# CakePHP Two Relationships Between Models

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have the following tables: `'assets', 'pictures', 'assets_pictures', 'othermodels', 'othermodels_pictures'`, etc...

From the above you probably already figured that table `'pictures'` serves as a repository of images and is related to multiple models, including 'assets'.

I want model `'Asset'` (table `'assets'`), to have:

1. `hasMany` relationship with `'Picture'` (using table `'assets_pictures'`)
2. `hasOne` relationship with `'Cover'` (table `'pictures'`), based on a `'cover_id'` field in `'assets'` associated with `'Picture.id'`

So far it seems to work when I setup `HABTM` relationship between `Asset` and `Picture`, and `'Asset' belongsTo 'Cover'`. Somehow this doesn't sound right, moreover changing the cover picture of an asset wipes out all `HABTM` relationships in `'assets_pictures'` for that asset, so I know something's wrong here. I'm at loss...

Comment: probabily you have to set `'unique' => 'keepExisting'` when setting up your HABTM relationship, take a look at the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't sound right because you are setting up multiple relationships between two tables at the database level. Not sure which ones, but this definitely breaks a few database normalization rules.

Imagine that later on you decide that you want to be able to track not only the cover, but also the back. You would have to add another field to the asset table called back_id, which would point back to pictures. A real mess...

The proper way to represent this is to include a 'type' field in the assets_pictures table:

[image: many to many relationship with additional data]

You can default this field to "normal" (or even null), and change it to "cover" when needed. Note that this field allows for additional  picture types (e.g. "back").

HABTM relationships can handle this without too many problems. The parameter **'unique'=>'keepExisting'** prevents CakePHP from dropping other relationships already in place (which is the default behavior).

However, things can get complicated with 'rich' HABTM relationships, particularly **when trying to save data**. If this happens, and before you pull out your hair, you may want to go down the ['hasMany through'](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model) route.

For convenience, and *to retrieve information*, you may want to set up an additional HABTM relationship for Cover in model Asset, which would look something like this:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Cover' => array(
        'className' => 'Picture',
        'conditions' => array('AssetCover.type' => 'cover'),
    )
```

Comment: Thanks a million Inigo Flores...! That makes perfect sense!

Comment: Great! I'm glad it helped.